# Proof using properties of Conditional Expectation with random vectors. Prove that $E(g(Y)|X)=E(g(Z)|X)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I have this problem with my probability homework.

I have to prove:

Let $(X,Y)$ and $(X,Z)$ be random vectors that have the same joint distribution and $g$ a measurable Borel function that verifies $E|g(X)| \leq \infty.$
Then:

$E(g(Y)|X)=E(g(Z)|X)$

I have to prove for indicator functions, simple functions and positive functions.

For indicator functions:

I took: $1_A=g(Y)$, $1_B=g(Z)$, with $A$ and $B$ $\in F$ with $F$ the $\sigma$ algebra.

I have that:

$E(g(Y)|X)=E(1_A|X)=P(A|X)$

$E(g(Z)|X)=E(1_B|X)=P(B|X)$

I do not know how  to continue the proof.

Comment: For any Borel set $B$,
$$
\mathsf{E}[g(Y)1\{X\in B\}]=\mathsf{E}[g(Z)1\{X\in B\}].
$$

Comment: Do you take X=$1_B$?

Comment: No. I take a set $\in\sigma(X)$.

Comment: Ok, but $1${$X\in B$ }is an indicator function, not a event of a sigma algebra

Comment: $X^{-1}(B)$ is an event in $\sigma(X)$.

Comment: ok, thank you I understand @d.k.o. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any bounded measurable function $h$

$$\mathbb{E}[g(Y)h(X)]=\mathbb{E}[g(Z)h(X)]$$

since $(Y,X)$ and $(Z,X)$ have the same (joint) distribution.

On the other hand

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[g(Y)h(X)]&=\mathbb{E}\big[\mathbb{E}[g(Y)|X]h(X)\big]\\
\mathbb{E}[g(Z)h(X)]&=\mathbb{E}\big[\mathbb{E}[g(Z)|X]h(X)\big]
\end{align}
$$

As these identities hold for any bounded measurable $h$, we obtain by definition of conditional expectation that

$$ \mathbb{E}[g(Y)|X]=\mathbb{E}[g(Z)|X]$$